# String format optional parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

Ola,

I don't have to much exp with the Swift language. I want to print into a String some variables and some of them are optional.

```
func onRegPin(timeOut: Int64, pin: String?)->()
{
  String(format: "Timeout: %d  Pin: %@", timeOut, pin!)
}
```

If the pin is nil at runtime I got some assert or something.

Is there a way to print this optional parameters using String ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:
`pinValue` is an empty string if `pin` is `nil` otherwise the unwrapped `pin` value

```
func onRegPin(timeOut: Int64, pin: String?)->()
{
  let pinValue = pin ?? ""
  String(format: "Timeout: %d  Pin: %@", timeOut, pinValue)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 func onRegPin(timeOut: Int64, pin: String?)->()
    {  if let pin = pin{
      String(format: "Timeout: %d  Pin: %@", timeOut, pin)
     }else{
      String(format: "Timeout: %d  No Pin ", timeOut)
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Using default Parameter

```
func onRegPin(timeOut: Int64, pin:String?="No pin"){
  String(format: "Timeout: %d  Pin: %@", timeOut, pin!)
}
```

If pin is nil call function only with `timeOut`

```
onRegPin(3423)
```

else if pin is not nil:

```
onRegPin(3423, pin:"Pin")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to unwrap the Optional before using it. The standard way in Swift 1.2 is with `if let` (there's also "nil coalescing" like in @vadian's answer).

Also it looks like your function should return a String, in my example it's an Optional because it could fail:

```
func onRegPin(timeOut: Int64, pin: String?) -> String? {
    if let pinOK = pin {
        return String(format: "Timeout: %d  Pin: %@", timeOut, pinOK)
    }
    return nil
}

if let regpin = onRegPin(30, "test") {
    println(regpin)   // prints "Timeout: 30  Pin: test"
}
```

With Swift 2 (Xcode 7) it could be:

```
func onRegPin(timeOut: Int64, pin: String?) -> String? {
    guard let pinOK = pin else { return nil }
    return String(format: "Timeout: %d  Pin: %@", timeOut, pinOK)
}

if let regpin = onRegPin(30, pin: "test") {
    print(regpin)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the idea was to not check "pin" or to introduce a new var for casting, There is another solution like println:

> String(format: "Timeout: %d Pin: %@", timeOut, "\(pin)")

Comment: While that's fine for logging, it should be noted that, if you're going to *show* this string somewhere, "String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value" – the result will look like "Optional(...)".